# MySQL, how can get the rows which was participated SUM operation by GROUP BY?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table like the one below:
[image]

I have this SQL code: which sums the `total_sale` and `total_rent` by grouping them by year and then ordering it by highest income descending and limiting only one record,

```
SELECT
    SUM(temp_t.total_sale + temp_t.total_rent) highest_income,
    temp_t.total_sale,
    temp_t.total_profit,
    temp_t.total_rent,
    temp_t.total_rent_expense,
    temp_t.total_expense,
    YEAR ( temp_t.the_date ) AS the_date
FROM
    ...
GROUP BY
    temp_t.grouping_column 
ORDER BY
    highest_income DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

When I run the code it shows me this output:
[image]

In the result row, I want to know which row of `total_rent` was used and so one for other columns, e.g.: I want the last row to be like this: because they all belong to 2022

`381266.9600    122961.9600    51163.9800    258305.00    16959.17    60780.00    2022`

Thanks!!

Comment: Please include the output you actually do want to see.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks for the reply! The expected output and the result output are all included. Thanks!

Comment: When you group by, it's in order to utilize the group functions.  You get one row per group by criteria.  Including other columns in the result set is meaningless, unless they are columns from the group by criteria.  Given the data as presented, you could utilize subqueries for the values you boxed in red, for example `(select max(total_rent)  FROM table) total_rent`.  Including the year of 2022 is not logical.  Your data as shown would include all values from 2022, but if the data changes, there might no longer be a relationship between the individual subqueries and one year.

Comment: @gview Hmm, OK! You are right, but because they all belong to 2022, I think if it was possible to get this data, because when I know the highest income year, then I want to know sale was how much and the rent was how much and also their expense. Although it seems meaningless, but here for me it is meaningful. Thanks!

Comment: Please never post images use text only. It would be much better if you add the data example , table description and expected result as text. A [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3aMmxpPT) would be nice. Also what MySQL version are you using ? Another problem you have is the sql_mode `only_full_group_by` which is disabled in your case , I strongly recommend enable and re-run the query

Comment: I use images for readability because can be marked as I did, and also I have already solved the problem. Focusing on the problem is better than focusing on meaningless things.

Comment: @BahramdunAdil your question will help future readers as well. As per *I use images for readability because can be marked as I did* , it is pointless and a waste of time to create a testing environment when OP uses image for data examples. *I have already solved the problem* you should post your own answer. As I already mentioned your query is invalid with sql_mode only_full_group_by enabled. As you can see none of those  above are **meaningless things** .

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this

```
SELECT
 SUM(total_sale + total_rent) AS highest_income,
 SUM(total_sale) AS total_sale,
 SUM(total_profit) AS total_profit,
 SUM(total_rent) AS total_rent,
 SUM(total_rent_expense) AS total_rent_expense,
 SUM(total_expense) AS total_expense,
 YEAR ( the_date ) AS the_date
FROM
 table
ORDER BY 1
GROUP BY 7
```

Comment: Sorry it is not the solution, you cannot sum `total_sale`,  `total_profit`, ...